# Differentiation of unspecified functions in Maple

Tags: maple

Lets say I have a function defined by f(A*sin(x)). I want to differentiate this function in Maple. That is ∂f(A*sin(x))/∂x = A*cos(x)*f’(A*sin(x)). However, Maple requires me to specify the function using the command `f := a -> y` for example. So I wish to know if it is possible to differentiate unspecified functions in Maple and if possible how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what you've claimed, Maple does not require you to specify `f` (as an operator, say).

Below, `f` is just some unassigned name. And you can call `diff` on an expression involving function calls to `f`.

```
restart;

expr := f(A*sin(x));

ans1 := diff(expr, x);

   D(f)(A*sin(x))*A*cos(x)
```

That result happens to be in `D` form, which is a convenient way to express the derivative of `f` evaluated at a point/value.

That result can also be represented in `diff` form (or `Diff`, its inert alternative). In this form we get a result involving a `diff` call. But that needs a variable of differentiation, and here that has to be some "dummy" name.

```
convert(ans1, diff);

   eval(diff(f(t1),t1),{t1 = A*sin(x)})*A*cos(x)
```

If you `convert` to `diff` form then any substitution for `f` by some concrete operator -- followed by evaluation -- would result in actual differentiation. But if you were to `convert` to inert `Diff` form then later substitution for `f` would not result in actual differentitation (unless, say, you utilized the `value` command on that result).